# Need to extract min and max value from an input variable. (Python)

Tags: python

my code basically asks people for their age. I need to get the average of ages and then the minimum and higher number between the answers given, but I don't know how to do that last part. I triend using (min(x)) but I keep getting this error code: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Any help would be appreciated.

```py
students= int(input('How many students are there in the class? '))
preguntas= int(input("A number lower than  "+str(students)+":  "))
i=0
totalAge=0

# MAIN CICLE

if questions<students:
    while i<questions:
        age= int(input("What's your age?"))
        totalAge+=age
        i= i+1
average= age/i
print ("The age average is "+str(average)+"")
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please add some code and show us what you've done and where you are stuck exactly. The info in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you frame your question in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

So as it seems that you are getting multiple inputs from the user (different ages) and you want to get the max and min from those ages.

So what you are doing wrong is you are providing only one input (x) to the min function which is wrong as min or max function is expecting an iterable (list, tuple, set etc) which has multiple elements and will give you minimum or maximum out of that.

So while getting input from the user, save that in some list;

```
lst = []

age = int(input("Enter your age:"))

lst.append(age)
```

Then after getting all the inputs;

```
maximum_age = max(lst)

minimum_age = min(lst)
```

In nutshell, this is the full solution;

```
lst = []

# running a loop just to get multiple inputs
for i in range(5):
  age = int(input("enter the age: "))
  # storing the input in the list lst
  lst.append(age)

# print average value
print(sum(lst)/len(lst))

# print maximum age
print(max(lst))

# print minimum age
print(min(lst))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it right now.

Comment: So I tried it but both are giving me the same value, could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: please upload the code.

Comment: I just uploaded the base one, without anything related to the min and max, thanks!

Comment: So what you are doing is you are adding the new age to the totalAge variable which will be a number at the end too. So it is completely non sense that you are trying to get the max and min from it ie, you are trying to get the numbers back which you added to it which cannot be done, So as i provided a better solution, instead of a totalAge variable, store the ages in a list as i did it.

Comment: Oh I see, this is like my third time programming so I really don't know much of what I'm doing. I'll do as you said, thanks a lot!

Comment: Everyone starts from scratch. So be motivated. Good luck.... And mark my answer as accepted if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` because the thing you are passing into x when you did `(min(x))` is an integer and not an iterable (like a list).

That is, doing `min(3)` does not make sense since, if you are trying to find the minimum of some values, it wouldn't make sense to pass just one value (i.e. the integer you are passing with `x`).

Instead, if you have a list like `mylist = [9, 2, 5, 13]`, then you can do `min(mylist)` which will give you the value `2`. This won't result in an error since a list is an iterable since you can *iterate* through it, unlike a sole integer which you can't iterate over.

Comment: You have a couple of choices of how you could tackle this. The first, as suggested by @alej, is to make a list of your ages and to use that since you can't take the minimum or maximum of a single value. Alternatively, you can track the min and max age as you go and update as required. Initiate two variables: `maxage = -inf` and `minage = inf` (you'll have have `from math import inf` beforehand, alternatively you could just use absurdly big and small values) and then in your loop do a check `if age > maxage` and `if age < minage` and update the values of `maxage` and `minage` as needed.

Comment: Will try that, I appreciate the help!